# How to intercept all methods annotated by @Validatable

Tags: java, aspectj

I have the annotation `@Validatable` and I want to intercept all calls to methods with that annotation returning `int`. For intsance:

```
@Validatable
public int method(){
   //...
}
```

How can I write the `pointcut` to do that? In general, I need to write the following aspect:

```
public aspect ValidateAspect {
    pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(__HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_PATTERN__);

    int around() : publicMethodExecuted() {
        //performing some validation and changing return value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform what you want once you get the annotations belonging to the `int method()` method using the following code :

```
pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public int <classname>.method());
int around() : publicMethodExecuted() {
  //performing some validation and changing return value
  MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
  String methodName = signature.getMethod().getName();
  Annotation[] annotations = thisJoinPoint.getThis().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName).getAnnotations();
  for (Annotation annotation : annotations)
      System.out.println(annotation);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ supports quite simply PointCut Designators for annotated method. For your use case, it is :

```
public aspect ValidateAspect {
    pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): @annotation(Validatable);

    int around() : publicMethodExecuted() {
        //performing some validation and changing return value
    }
}
```